# install ubuntu from usb drive when boot order is not changable

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, mint

Problem:

- ubuntu 14.04 installation disk is ready on a usb drive
- trying to install it on a laptop with mint os
- can't change boot order -> can't boot from the usb drive

What I would like to know:

1. can I boot from the usb drive in this situation?
2. is there any other way to initiate the installation process other than boot from the usb drive?

Comment: Did you access your BIOS to check and edit the boot device preferences?

Comment: Maybe you have a special key [F9 for me], which opens up instead of the BIOS all available bootable devices, and you may choose which to launch?